# Would a spear ever out perform a bow when wielded by an insanely powerful person?

Tags: medieval, strength, archery

I am writing a story where humans are battling monsters (Think orcs, goblins, dire wolves, etc).

I wanted to stay away from the typical ‘go for guns’ and try historical weaponry. I know the bow has longer reach and potentially more lethality. But how much is that the design/materials of the weapon?

Is there a point where an insanely strong human could throw a spear further/harder than that same person wielding a bow? A point where the type of design/materials wouldn’t be able to compensate for raw throwing strength?

The humans in question could be as ‘weak’ as Captain America, or as strong as Thor.

Comment: (1) [*Spears*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear) are typically strong and heavy and not for throwing. You are thinking of a [*javelin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javelin). (2) A javelin is very much heavier than an arrow; that is why the arrow will always go farther. (3) Javelins and arrows have different use cases.

Comment: Are natural things not tougher to compensate for Thor level strong people around? Because if so, the world is just gonna fracture around them.

Comment: Is a thrown spear actually less powerful than an arrow? I imagine it is impossible to throw as far, and is slower but also heavier so impacts harder. But less powerful -- who knows? There are tons of videos on youtube of [people testing out medieval weapons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGSL7XApz2s) on [pieces of armor and ballistic jelly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqkiKjBQe7U) for you to research.

Comment: In war, a lot of arrows don't hit anything, but many arrows are used. With lots of arrows in the air, some hit important targets. For example, in 1066, it was a stray arrow that killed the English King allowing the Normans to take over. Spears have a similar use but the thrower has higher hopes to hit something. Spears might be used as a "stabbing device" and not even thrown. Think of arrows for when foes are farther away and a spear for when they are near.

Comment: Referencing Captain America and Thor, who have rather undefined strength, it seems like you could just declare that your spear-chucker is stronger than a puny bow. After all, to quote Spiderman in reference to Cap's shield "that thing does not obey the laws of physics".

Comment: Worth noting that using a spear/javelin is a lot easier to learn than using a bow, which could be relevant in your story.

Comment: Alternatively, have your humans fight the monsters in their dens, underground, in narrow winding cave systems. In an environment like that, you want (short) spears, not bows and arrows.

Comment: Why are you not first referring at least to the umpteen techie documentaries available all over TV, let alone the WWW, dealing specifically with how arrows or spears work?

Comment: There is a spear-throwing historical weapon called the "Atlatl" that can make a person throw a spear way further and is simpler and cheaper to make than bows and arrows, I suggest looking it up, it may suit ya

Comment: Consider using an spear-thrower/Atlatl, blow darts, or even a sling and rock for an interesting alternative. Each have pro's and cons and can be used to aid or hinder in different situations.

Comment: @AlexP by most definitions, javelins are a type of spear

Comment: Only Thor level strong?  Why not say, Thanos level strong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Interestingly (to me, at least), the most important thing is not so much *strength* but *speed*. If you could throw a little metal dart at 500m/s then you might well be able to drop someone in full plate armor because your throwing arm is comparable to a modern firearm, even if you didn't have cartoon-like ultra-strength enough to lift and hurl an ox, etc.

The fastest normal-human sportsballers can throw at perhaps ~100mph (~160km/h)... both [cricket](https://cricnerds.com/featured/fastest-bowler-in-the-world/) and [baseball](https://www.electro-mech.com/team-sports/baseball/the-fastest-baseball-pitchers-ever/) have records at that sort of speed. A big javelin flung at that sort of speed is obviously pretty bad news if it hits you, but it'll be harder to aim (because it won't have a trajectory as flat at the bullet-like dart) and it'll take longer to cross the same distance requiring a bit more thought when dealing with moving targets or strong cross-winds, and so seems like it wouldn't are at all well with skinny-mc-bullet-chucker

Bows are of course very much subject to material limits. It is interesting to note that whilst siege weapons like the [catapulta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catapulta) or [ballista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballista) could indeed outrange a human with a bow, mostly what they could do was throw a much heavier projectile at fairly similar speeds. I don't believe there was much scope for historical bows to have a significantly higher initial projectile velocity than they did (for a ballpark figure, this testing of [arrow speeds](http://greenmanlongbows.co.uk/SPEED%20TESTING%20Measuring%20the%20arrow%20speed%20of%20bows%20and%20longbows%20using%20a%20chronometer.htm) had a top speed of a little over 120mph from a modern non-composite 64lb longbow which probably wasn't firing war-weight arrows). I suspect this means that if your superhumans could fling a projectile at over 120mph, they might reasonably expect to outperform a bow shooting a projectile of a similar weight, even if the bow had crazy siege-weapon-like draw weights.

It is important to consider accuracy, though. Long range descending projectiles are always going to be hard to aim, and whilst ancient siege weapons might have had a deadly range of 450m, their effective accurate range was probably closer to a third of that, if you were shooting at human-sized targets.Humans are good at throwing, sure, but I'd say that throwing a javelin is much harder to do with high accuracy  than shooting a bow.

Siege weapon ammunition is big, heavy, and awkward to make compared to regular war-arrows, and you shouldn't waste it by throwing it at distant, small, moving targets. If your superhumans aren't attacking fortifications by throwing rocks at them, they should be charging in and throwing javelins and darts and the like at much closer range, where they can much more reliably hit and maximize their benefits over regular bow-shot.

---

*edit*

Who are your supers fighting? If they're fighting people of equivalent strength and speed, then you'll find that they'll be able to carry such heavy shields and armor that in combination with their super-strength and super-reflexes mean that projectile weapons just aren't a threat to them.

They're gonna square off against each other, at close range, with weapons optimised for crushing or opening heavy armor that no human could carry. They'll be much closer to *real* tanks than RPG tanks with sexy abs'n'boobs enhancing armor. Spears and arrows are only good for wasting the rank and file, not the elite.

Real-world knights kinda went this way too. Swords aren't really that good against serious full-plate (and half-swording is a *compromise*, people) and so heavy armor ruled up until the advent of decent musketry.

---

*edit 2*

- Problem: you can't create a bow better than your superheroes' throwing arms due to material limits.
- Observation: your superheroes have bones and tendons and ligaments and skin and maybe even hair that can survive extreme forces and rapid movement.
- Solution: manufacture composite super-bows from the bodies of your enemies.

Suddenly archers, in a rather gristly form, are back in the game.

Comment: You make a lot of solid points. 

I wanted to make a realistic take on the whole RPG-leveling trope (if that is even possible) where the MC starts off as an ordinary human with 10 points across the board in Strength, Dexterity, Perception, etc. At the beginning, the bow would be a better choice compared to a javelin or throwing spear, seeing as the design of the bow would do much of the work for them. But what if we go from 10 points to a 100, or a 1000 even? At some point, the design of the bow would fall behind the sheer power and speed from the javelin when thrown by the MC.

Comment: I wanted to check if this is indeed the case, where the javelin/spear would eventually outrange the bow entirely, or if, like with the bow, there is a limiting factor at play in its design.

You make valid points about the accuracy part, but at +500 meters what wouldn’t lose its accuracy because of gravity, wind, etc.

Comment: Upvote for "material limits" which I think is the most relevant thing here.  In the real world material limits also pertains to muscle and ligaments of the thrower / shooter.  If Thor is allowed then those limits are dismissed since he can shimmy about in a metal-melting blast of radiation and keep his clothes on.

Comment: @Willk "and keep his clothes on" - unless they're flicked away by another similarly-powered god :)

Comment: @OsiriumWrites **accurately** and **quickly** shooting *lots of* arrows (like during a battle, as opposed to shooting *one deer*) requires more than average strength, and *especially* dexterity and perception.

Answer (score 19):

## Even without super strength a spear can outperform

The question in the title is about out performing. The question in the description is about reaching father/harder. I would focus on 'out performing' in killing or taking opponents out of the fight.

As a general rule an arrow fired from a bow is less heavy than a spear. This makes it go a further distance at a higher speed when launched with identical energy. The spear has more mass, requiring more energy than an arrow to get to the same speed.

But here is the twist. Spears generally have more energy behind them. They might go slower, but the impact is much more dangerous. This is incredibly important for your targets! Most arrows do not give a high panic reaction and the pain also isn't very high. If nothing vital is hit, which is mostly by cutting major arteries, the target is very much still standing. Your targets seem to be bigger and tougher monsters. They can lose more blood and get more damage than a human. You want more stopping power. Arrows are good, but spears can really get in there and do damage.

I understand you want more distance between you and monsters, but if arrows do not do enough damage except with lucky shot, or might not even penetrate deep enough, you need heavier weapons. Without super powers spears would already out perform against monsters compared to an arrow.

### Farther than a bow

It is still possible to throw a spear further than a bow for a super powered person. The bows have material limits, whereas your super powered soldiers are upgraded beyond biological limits. If you would give captain America a bow you would probably not reach the limit with the English long bows. However, halfway up the ladder to Thor they could already snap the bow by drawing the string. They can throw a spear much further than a bow.

However, bows were build with the limits of humans in mind. You might still be able to build a bow of special iron for example, which wouldn't break in the hands of super powered soldiers.

Even so I would choose spears. In cost a spear is comparable to an arrow, as the most cost is in the crafting and not the materials. As they are very similar this is about the same. Spears are more sturdy, have more mass to drive into a body, are less in danger to shatter and can be used very well in keeping distance in close quarters fighting. They are probably preferred above nearly all other weapons in a close quarters engagement against monsters because of their reach.

### TL:DR

The spear travels less far, but in real life already has more energy behind it than an arrow. It is preferred against bigger monsters. For super powered soldiers it is also more sturdy and reusable, only marginally more expensive than an arrow and only has the biological constraints to deal with. Lastly if a monster closes the gap it is the preferred choice of weapon. The spear allows you to keep as much distance between you and your opponent as possible, while being an excellent individual and team weapon to do damage.

Comment: I can’t think of a physical reason why it would be impossible to build bows with much higher draw strength. For example crossbows generally have much higher draw strength in a similar size.

Comment: In terms of a spear being more powerful, a stone headed spear thrown with a spear thrower like [this one from Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woomera_(spear-thrower)), has about 4 times the force behind it is an arrow from a compound bow. Source: the end of [this article](https://www.smh.com.au/national/extinctions-group-theory-20040625-gdj7cy.html). Additionally, a superhuman wouldn't need a spear thrower, but if they had one alongside a spear with a sharp metal head, they would be a very formidable force indeed.

Comment: Thor  can't break a regular longbow by drawing it normally. The amount of energy stored in the bow depends not on how strong the archer is, but on how far the string is pulled back. And when shooting an arrow, Thor, like anyone else, is limited by the length of his upper arm, about twenty inches.  To get better performance from a bow, Thor needs one made of special materials, too stiff to be drawn by a human.

Comment: @Michael I concur. That Is why I suggested the same with stronger bows. However, I do think such bows would reach the material limit as well if we talk about people on the road to or as strong as MCU Thor. Someone who can dent an incredibly durable gold-titanium alloy by squeezing their fingers will hit any bow material limit with ease by my estimate. By how the wold is worded advanced materials seem to be in short supply.

Comment: @MarkDominus most of the energy is stored in the bow and not the string. If it is limited by how far the string is pulled back (which is solved by a sturdier string) you are limited by the bow for the drawing distance. It would still put spears ahead, as Thor has a lot more strength left over with a bow. Of course we get limited by speed with spears, much like a boat running with the wind instead of beam reach. Yet we have leverage in the launchers that B-K suggests, allowing strength to be better used for speed.

Comment: If steel is allowed you could make something similar to an Arbalest, but without the crank (windlass): “The strongest windlass-pulled arbalests could have up to 22 kN (2,200 kilograms-force; 4,900 pounds-force) of force and be accurate up to 100 m (110 yards).” That’s ~40 times the force of a warbow.

Comment: Yes, my point is that Thor's superior strength doesn't get better performance out of a regular bow, because he can't store more energy in the bow than anyone else with normal-sized arms.  In particular he cannot snap the bow by pulling the string as you said, because the bow holds the same amount of energy regardless of who is pulling it.

Comment: "Spears generally have more energy behind them" - Are you sure about that? The whole point of a bow is to store energy over a longer period of time and release it all at once. The spear is limited to whatever energy you can impart it over the duration of the throw.

Comment: The massive English longbows had immense power, more than enough to cleave through a knight in full armor (their range was more than 300m).

Comment: Heavy projectiles retain energy much better than lighter ones, giving advantage to the spear if they're launched with the same energy at range.

Comment: @Michael you're right about crossbows.  If OP wants to hit monsters hard from a long way away, he needs *ballista* (big, crew-served Roman crossbows).

Comment: Downside: Your quiver can hold a whole bunch of arrows.  If you throw your spear, you're temporarily unarmed until you retrieve it.  You could carry backup spears, but all things being equal, you can't carry as many spears as arrows.

Comment: @Aetol I was skeptical at first too, but the time needed to draw a bow seems comparable to the time needed to throw a spear - it's not like the bow draw is storing energy over a significantly longer period. An arrow might travel a few times faster than a thrown spear, but has just a fraction of the mass, I expect the kinetic energy is comparable between both projectiles. Lower speed and higher mass also cause the spear to lose less energy to drag, delivering more of the energy imparted at launch.

Comment: @MarkDominus It occurs to me that every time I've seen a bow drawn, one arm is straight and the other bent almost 180° at the elbow. I suppose one could in principle extend both arms to straight. I don't know people don't, but speculate that it is easier to aim with the end of the shaft near your eye, and so bows are designed to be at the human limit in a pose that achieves that. If so, perhaps Thor could get better performance out of a regular bow (but a modified, longer arrow) by extending both arms and using superhuman ballistic calculations to compensate for the reduced ease of aiming.

Comment: @Michael high strength does not mean faster (thus farther) projectile after a certain point, you hit the limit of how fast the bow arms can move before you even reach the high end crossbows. Thee was a question about this before, crossbows speeds max out at a certain point. above a certain point you get higher projectile weight but the same speed.

Comment: @Aetol just back of the envelope for a warbow arrow 0.077kg times 85m/s (6.6 kg.m/s) while a spear is 1kg times 25m/s (25kg.m/s) its a huge difference, arrows are just too light compared to the difference in speed.

Comment: @John that is momentum. Energy is 1/2 m v^2. That gives 278J vs 312J, using your numbers. They are almost identical. However, momentum is also very important in terminal ballistics.

Comment: This is also why early guns started outcompeting bows even when they took much longer to reload. If the enemy charges you and you shoot arrows at them, it's not much use if they bleed out ten minutes later, but they can still crash through your front lines before that. However, being hit by a bullet can take an enemy [out of action immediately](https://youtu.be/YZiHomrRGnA?t=778). So, a heavy javelin can be more useful than a bow, in case the enemy is charging you and is quite resilient. You want that enemy to stop *right now*, and not ten minutes later due to blood loss.

Comment: @Aron Momentum is what you care about since it gets conserved, it is a predictor of penetration which is how both weapons kill. unlike bullets both are low kinetic energy weapons.  kinetic energy is less important for things like arrows. keep in mind 50 joules the difference between arrows used to hunt rabbits and those used to hunt moose.   https://www.nockout.com/understanding-the-momentum-and-kinetic-energy-of-arrows/

Answer (score 5):

While not an expert in the subject, my common sense is telling me the answer is no. The bow is a force multiplier, using the coiled tension within the wood and string to deliver more power than the arm could supply on its own. The only reason why it wouldn't be advantageous to use a bow would be if the material of the bow were to snap under the pressure. However, the existence of siege weaponry, as well as the makeup of modern bows and crossbows, shows us that the upper limits of a bow's tensile strength can be pushed quite far, even at lower levels of technology. Heavy ballistas, catapults, and even hand crossbows existed as early as 400 or perhaps even 600 BC, and were certainly normalized among leading military powers by 200 BC, meaning that ancient or medieval societies should absolutely have the capability to make bows for super strong humans.

Thus, it seems to me that if you can draw a bow back without breaking it or snapping its string, the arrow loosed would travel further and with more power than if the same push were given to a spear - also, necessarily, with more accuracy. Furthermore, if we are to believe that the person drawing the bow is so strong that they would break it, surely the same limitations apply to the thrown object. A spear thrown with such great force would likely shatter upon impact, rendering it a deadly but ultimately inefficient and unpredictable weapon. Either way, I suspect the bow would be better.

A compromise between the two lies in the Atl-atl, an ancient spear throwing technology. If you beleive that your superhumans are so strong that they would snap the string of any bow made for them, using a pure leverage device like the atl-atl still adds the accuracy and force multiplication that makes such a weapon reliably dangerous without having a weak link. Historically, bows replaced atl-atls for a reason, and I still think that some manner of bow would work best (crossbows, compact bows, longbows and recurve bows all offer different working solutions to the problems that an intense draw strength might pose to the structural integrity of the weapon). But if you really like the rule-of-cool image of your super strong humans throwing stuff because "no bow can handle their raw power," I think giving them atl-atls would add a fun touch while also answering the accuracy issue.

Answer (score 4):

"Is there a point where an insanely strong human could throw a spear further/harder than that same person wielding a bow?"

**Short answer:**  No.

**Longer answer:**  It's still very definitely no.

A bow is a force multiplier.

The stronger he is the stronger the bow he can use.

So he will always outperform himself with a custom bow than with a spear.

> For any professional archer custom bows are entirely par for the course, and it's the same for amateurs, even today buying a modern bow in a sports shop you will still *always* buy a bow with a poundage according to your ability to string and pull it.

The only time your hero might do better with a spear, no matter how insanely strong he is, is if for some reason he didn't have access to his own bow and all he had available were his puny human companions bows, then, and only then, he might concievably be better off chucking a pointy stick.

Comment: Bows (and similar weapons) have limits on how fast their limbs (and therefore the projectile) can accelerate/move. If your superhuman was not just superstrong but also superfast (i.e. able to move their limbs faster than a bow) they might be better off throwing the projectile bare handed.

Comment: @Michael Yes, it's just a shame that the OP only specified super strength isn't it  otherwise you might actually have a valid point 

Answer (score 4):

A spear or javelin would outperform in terms of sheer mass/energy, but they're not touching a bow on *accuracy*.  That mighty javelin is nil if you can't hit your target with it!  Or worse, you hit in a non-critical spot and just made the monster mad...

So let's give our insanely powerful warrior the best of both worlds: a ballista-sized crossbow which only they have the strength to wield and arm.  A fast javelin-sized bolt with high accuracy is bound to ruin many-a monster's day.

Answer (score 4):

If your humans have space to carry them, there's a third solution - the [atlatl, or spear-thrower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spear-thrower?wprov=sfla1).

The atlatl is effectively a much older and much deadlier version of those plastic tennis ball throwers people use to play fetch with their dogs. It's a straight shaft, usually as long as the user's forearm, with a cup at the end to support the spear. To use it, hold the atlatl in your throwing hand and pull your arm back. Place the spear on the shaft with the end of it in the cup, and swing. The cup is shaped so that it releases the spear when your arm reaches the top of its arc, and the spear flies away much faster than you could throw it normally.

Physics-wise, the atlatl is just as simple as its construction. When you throw a spear, you accelerate it using the muscles in your wrist, elbow, and shoulder. The rest of your arm acts as a lever that applies that force over a long distance so that the spear is moving as quickly as possible when you throw it. Using an atlatl extends the length of that lever (usually by about 50%), which means that the end holding the spear moves an even longer distance when you throw. Because your arm still takes the same amount of time to rotate when you throw, end of the atlatl moves much faster than your hand, and so does the spear.

Although your soldiers probably wouldn't be able to reach bow ranges using an atlatl, they could definitely throw much farther than without one even without super strength, and a faster spear would also do more damage. A human with super strength could use an atlatl just as easily as anyone else, and there's not really a limit to how fast they can throw one - bows can only be drawn with so much force before something breaks, but an atlatl is just a really fast stick. Historically, atlatls were used to throw darts, which were about 8 feet long and had a very thin, very light, and very fragile shaft - in other words, a terrible spear. However, an atlatl can be used to throw anything that's relatively dart-shaped, so your soldiers could easily throw their spears with them, albeit at shorter ranges. If they're willing to make some minor modifications to their spears, they could add large fletching to the rear to create a kind of spear-dart hybrid. The fletching won't increase range, but they will make them more accurate, which is just as important.

PS: If you go the hybrid route, use helical fletching, which spirals around the shaft at a very slight angle. It spins the spear the same way rifling spins a bullet for even more accuracy.

Comment: There is a reason that the spears were flimsy. They break inside the game animal, causing more damage.; Also, a light spear is easier to throw. A heavier spear might be impossible or difficult or even impossible to throw. IDK.

Comment: @NomadMaker : heavy javelins (called "pilum") were used by the Romans, so that if an enemy catches one with a shield, the shield will become useless with that heavy javelin being embedded into it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question presumes it, but a spear doesn't have to be thrown.

- A phalanx of soldiers can march forward, spears bristling, and hold ground
- A spear can be used to stab with more force than a held arrow
- A spear can be used as a makeshift punji stick against charging cavalry
- A spear can be used as an effective melee weapon at close range (the point and the shaft)

Answer (score 2):

Consider the materials science of your world.  Perhaps spears are better because they are incapable of making a bow that taps  the full strength.   The bow breaks first.  Either the cord or the bow itself.

Javelins do not require flexibility the way a bow does.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The bow accumulates the strength provided by the movement of the archer that lasts about a second (Two seconds if the archer is weak) and uses that power concentrating it in a fraction of a second. The human in question should not be just insanely strong, to throw a spear at a decent speed that human should also be insanely fast and agile. Agile otherwise the joints and the tendons would break, fast because this is a movement that requires a complex coordination.

All those qualities together would be very difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason the spear wouldn't be more deadly, either way you can only expect to hit what you're aiming at. Beyond a certain distance I would expect a spear to perform better as numerous ancient sources cite the effect of wind on arrows. Whereas a spear has a lot more mass and would be less affected.

But if you really want to make a mess of the monsters.....

[Why not go for a sling?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqu-plfFFj4) It outranges a bow, and can be improvised in seconds with ammo just lying on the ground at your feet. You can just chuck big rocks instead of stones. The range and power is a multiplier of your strength rather than reliant on a bows draw. So the stronger you are the further and harder you can throw.

I throw large stones because I like the way they hit, but with smaller ones 100 mph is not a problem, a real slinger would do lot more I would think.[image: Sling improvised from potato sack]

Comment: ...and also a great opportunity to invert the David vs. Goliath trope

Comment: @DavidGelhar yep, would be a much more interesting and effective weapon to build a story on IMO

Comment: @DavidGelhar Beorn slinging stones at hobgoblins would be a great visual.

Comment: A sling does *not* outrange a bow.  Not even a staff sling.  The English longbow as used in the 11th to 14th century had a lethal range of nearly 400 meters, and if made heavier for a stronger archer, with matched arrows, could easily exceed that figure.  The stone or bullet from a sling won't hold velocity as well or penetrate as well on impact even at the same velocity.

Comment: @ZeissIkon how would you know? Romans and Greeks both asserted that slings outranged and were more dangerous than bows. Longbow wasn't widely used, but 400 metres? So what? We can sling further than that today recreationally. Professional slingers would I assume do a lot more. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sling_(weapon). And a staff sling does not outperform a normal one. It just allows a person to throw bigger stones but has drawbacks. I have used both for years

Comment: @Kilisi You're comparing maximum range of a sling against documented effective range of a bow, i.e. can you actually hit anything smaller than a phalanx at that range?  And even when slings were common, there were composite bows with heavy enough draw to cast a heavy arrow as far as a sling bullet -- but more accurately.  We're also talking superhuman archers; they might rival an arbalest or Roman scorpion -- the latter of which could cast a bolt the size of a javelin more than a quarter mile with accuracy to hit a single human.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Thats a strawman argument, do you think people could hit what they aimed at at 400 metres with a long bow? I cannot even think why you deem a bow more accurate. Distance isn't the accuracy limiter with a sling.. So I assume you're not familiar with either weapon. Another huge difference between an arrow and a sling is that at long distance I can see the arrow and dodge, You can't even see the stone. In terms of hunting and war at long range this would be very important.

Comment: @kilisi You seriously think you can see an incoming arrow, point on, I've seen demonstration of why you shouldn't shoot an arrow straight up in the air: it becomes invisible well before it starts to fall back, and you don't know where to dodge to.  Beyond that, an arrow is more suited to printing a small group at reasonable distance than a non-rifled sling bullet (which will tumble and tend to wander randomly around its main trajectory), hence is more accurate; it also penetrates better for the same weight and velocity.

Comment: @ZeissIkon sorry, you make little sense to me, feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The WR for javelin throw is just ~100m -- and that's with a technique focused on maxxing distance instead of accuracy.

Any amateur archer can easily outperform that distance with a compound bow. If we ignore accuracy and focus just on distance like javelin throwers do, top marks for longest bow shot get to ~1200m (~1900m if you include crossbows).

But just distance won't do much in combat. You need accuracy.

Current *accurate* bow shot WR is about ~250m. On the other hand, while I've not been able to find current records for accurate spear throwing, general consensus sets a historical range for it of... 10m. Yup, just one zero there.
Considering that specialized athletes usually outperform average humans, let's be generous and settle for ~25m of range for an accurate spear throw.

This means shooting arrows outperforms throwing spears by 10x-20x both in pure reach and accurate reach.

But we're talking superhumans here. Spears are heavier and carry more energy. Wouldn't a superhuman capable of a 250m accurate spear throw come out on top?

Sure! But then again, **what's stopping your superhuman of building themself a bow that shoots spear-sized arrows**?

If this superhuman can accurately throw a spear to something 250m away, applying the same 10x-20x factor, with a bow (and eagle-like vision) they could probably hit targets 1km away.

Imagine a warrior with a bow that shoots frigging javelins instead of arrows. How cool would that be?

---

TL;DR: Shooting a pointy stick with a bow always outperforms throwing it with your arm. If you want to throw bigger and heavier sticks, just build bigger and heavier bows.

Comment: Bows work best in huge volleys. Yes, it's wasteful of arrows, but you stand a much better chance of hurting one or more of your opponents.

Answer (score 1):

To be safe from monsters, humans would build fortifications.

In order to throw a spear with decent force, the thrower must take at least three steps to gather momentum, which makes it impossible to throw it from the walkway on the top of the ramparts. For the same reason, a spear can't be fired from cover, or through a hole in the wall, or a machicolation:

[image]

In the thick of the woods, or in a monster cave, a spear would perhaps be too long, awkward to maneuver, it would bump into obstacles. But an archer is much more maneuverable, and can hide behind a bush, even shoot through foliage without being seen.

In all these circumstances, your overpowered humans' ranged weapon of choice would probably be a heavy bow with heavy arrows.

Now, there's the atlatl. Throwing spears that are propelled with an atlatl are essentially longer arrows. They are lightweight and flexible:

[image]

They must be springy. When thrown, the spear bends, storing energy, then it springs forth. This gives it a higher speed than a simple throw, but it means it can't be used as a non-throwing spear to skewer someone: it would be too flexible and wobbly.

Combat spears used as a two-handed weapon have to be stiff, therefore heavy, therefore hard to throw.

The wounding ability of a projectile depends on its kinetic energy, so a light fast projectile beats a heavy slow one.

Now... your super strong humans would most likely be using crossbows instead.

The crossbow has many advantages. It requires much less training than a bow, anyone can be accurate with it pretty quick. And it allows a huge draw weight with medieval materials. Its main issue is that it is heavier and slow to reload, because normal humans are not strong enough, so they have to use a winch. However, a super strong human would just pull the string back while inserting a new bolt, making reloading much quicker, a second or two. Weight would also be much less of an issue.

Throwing spears also have the ammo issue: you can't realistically carry more than one. Where will you put a bunch of 2m long spears? In a quiver on your back? It has to be a two handed weapon, or it will bump into absolutely everything, get stuck into door frames, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, eventually spears win because of material limits.

People have already touched on the strength limits of bows and the suggestion as been made to use the bodies of one's enemies--that might work for not breaking but there's still the issue of how much energy they can store.

However, there's another material limit that can't be handwaved: for your projectile to survive the launch.  Your projectile is being driven from behind, eventually you'll reach a point where the projectile itself can't stand up to the acceleration.  Furthermore, a bow delivers very uneven acceleration, most of it is at the start, whereas a spear is accelerated reasonably uniformly.  For the same strength projectile you can therefore attain a higher final speed with a spear.  You also have the advantage that the spear is heavier and thus packs more energy for the same speed.